# How many triangles in picture?

Tags: geometry, puzzle

Can you tell me how many triangles are in this picture? I've counted 96, not sure that I got right answer.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could try counting them by using the symmetry of the shape (if you haven't already).

Comment: Clearly there are 19 unique points. Number of triangles that can be formed from 19 points taking 3 at a time=$19\choose3$. Also note that some of the points lie on a straight line. When we took $19\choose3$ we included the ones that lie on a straight line. Perhaps finding the number of lines and subtracting that from $19\choose3$ will yield the answer.

Comment: @GTXOC I see 19 unique points...

Comment: Alright I missed the ones in the middle of the base.

Comment: @All: Not all triangles are valid even if the points could form one, consider lines between "star-corners".

Comment: I was always interested in mathematical approach to these kinds of problems. Just counting them doesn't seem like a proof/solution to me.

Comment: @ Alex R : For this reason, I deleted a hint that i'am giving   based on the same idea. Thank's!

Answer (score 3):

Let's see! We'll break it up into the following cases (where an *apex* means one of the six points of the star):

*A: Triangles that contain three apexes*
There are 2 of these.

*B: Triangles that contain a pair of opposite apexes*
For each such pair, there are 2 of these, so 6 in total.

*C: Triangles that contain a pair of non-opposite apexes*
For each non-adjacent apex pair, there are three of these, so 18 in total.

*D: Triangles that contain exactly one apex*
For each apex, I count 10 such triangles, so 60 in total.

*E: Triangles that contain no apex*
For each edge of the internal hexagon, there are 3 triangles, so 18 in total.

I make that 2 + 6 + 18 + 60 + 18 = 104.

Comment: I verified and this seems to be correct.

Comment: Look OK to me too, though categories $D$ and $E$ could be somewhat refined.

Comment: @Marc: I agree with you about category D.

Comment: A small reality check:  If you dismiss the two big equilateral triangles, all other triangles belong to orbits of $6$ under rotations by $2\pi/6$, so $T-2$ must be divisible by $6$, which $T=104$ is but $T=96$ (the OP's original count) is not.

Comment: For Category $D$, you can take the apex at the very top and count triangles that are and aren't symmetric across the "$y$"-axis.  There are $2$ that are and $4$ pair that aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I only get 98.  I am missing the 3rd triangle under section C.  I only see 2 triangles that contain a pair of non-opposite apexes.